# Blazor webassembly plugin app gives "is not contained by the base URI" error, how to override it?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am attempting to create a Blazor plugin ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70239683/how-to-load-a-blazor-app-as-a-plugin-embed-in-another-domain/70949255#70949255)) that can be embedded in any random domain (call it randomClientDomain.com).

Everything seems to load but blazor.webassembly.js throws "*The URI 'https://SomeRandomDomain.com' is not contained by the base URI 'https://politachat.com/plugin'*"

For this specific error the index.html on randomClientDomain.com includes:

```
<head>
    <base href="/" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="PolitaChatPlugin" class="col-11"></div>
    <script src="https://politachat.com/plugin/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script> 
         // some code omitted for brevity
</body>
```

and my Program.cs in the Blazor app is:

`builder.Services.AddTransient(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("/") });`

I've tried just about every combination for `<base>` and `HttpClient` (edit: including ensuring the trailing forward slash is present in BaseAddress, where needed). I think the error is correct, but non-applicable in my case. Is it possible to fix it, or at least have it ignored?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is HttpClient BaseAddress not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23438416/why-is-httpclient-baseaddress-not-working)

Comment: @Yogi 
No, that's unrelated.  I've edited the question to reflect that. Appreciate the help though.

Comment: In .NET 6 there are [Blazor Custom Elements](https://github.com/aspnet/AspLabs/tree/main/src/BlazorCustomElements) which mght help, but I've not found any examples of making a Blazor component work across domains.